# erlang: What does the first line in the erlang shell mean?

Tags: erlang

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 26 [erts-14.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [jit] [dtrace]
```

What does each piece of the erlang shell mean?
I am especially interested in these

[smp:8:8]

[ds:8:8:10]

[async-threads:1]

[jit]

[dtrace]

Comment: Not a real answer, but just more info. The line comes from https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/43d2f9b647f03b55a423f156446411cd4c04f271/erts/emulator/beam/erl_bif_info.c#L85-L155 and it reflects the values of a lot of C Macros and environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

#### Options:

**`smp`**

From [doc](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#emulator-flags):

> `+S Schedulers:SchedulerOnline`
> Sets the number of scheduler threads to create and scheduler threads to set online ...

If you run `erl +S 10` you'll see `[smp:10:10]`

**`ds`**

From [doc](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#emulator-flags):

> `+SDcpu DirtyCPUSchedulers:DirtyCPUSchedulersOnline`
> Sets the number of dirty CPU scheduler threads to create and dirty CPU scheduler threads to set online ...

If you run `erl +SDcpu 7` you'll see `[ds:7:7:10]`

The third number is `+SDio DirtyIOSchedulers`

**`async-threads`**

From [doc](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#emulator-flags):

> `+A size`
> Sets the number of threads in async thread pool ... The async thread pool is used by linked-in drivers to handle work that may take a very long time ...

If you run `erl +A 10` you'll see `[async-threads:10]`

**`jit`**

[Erlang JIT](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/beamasm#faq) is enabled

**`dtrace`**

I'm not knowledgeable about this one, but seems to be [this page](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/runtime_tools/dtrace#supported-platforms)

#### To elaborate a little more about the schedulers:

The BEAM starts a number of OS-threads to run the emulator (schedulers, `+S`), but there's native code (nif/vm code) that may take a long time to complete and it may stall the VM if run normally, so this is (should be) run in dirty schedulers:

- Dirty CPU: Typical users of the dirty CPU schedulers are large garbage collections, json protocol encode/decoders written as nifs and matrix manipulation libraries.
- Dirty IO: Typical users of the dirty IO schedulers are reading and writing to files.

And the async-thread pool is used for linked-in drivers, which have mostly been migrated to dirty IO schedulers